# Need to Retrieve the Outlook App Selected mail item using Javascript(office.js)

Tags: javascript, java, outlook, office-js

I need to upgrade my code which is already written on vbscript. Code used to fetch selected mail from Outlook App. So I searched and find that Office.js will help us to retrieve mail from outlook. I tried it in local by referring office.js as below. But I can't able to retrieve mail object.Office.initialize return anonymous, Office.context.mailbox return undefined.

```js
Office.initialize = function () {
      // Checks for the DOM to load using the jQuery ready function.
      /* $(document).ready(function () { */
        // After the DOM is loaded, app-specific code can run.
        var item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
        var subject = item.subject;
        // Continue with processing the subject of the current item,
        // which can be a message or appointment.
      //});
    };
```

what is the issue in my code or suggest any alternatives.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get the code working and initializing correctly you need to develop a web add-in. The Office runtime initializes the add-in by calling a corresponding callback. You may ask how does it know where to find the callback?

The answer is in the manifest file where developers typically specify the files that should be invoked by the runtime. Read more about web add-ins in the [Office Add-ins platform overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins) page in MSDN.

Comment: For reading the existing outlook inbox selected item ,Is it required to create a web add in.